# RSA private key DER decode fails without CRT components

Tags: openssl, asn.1, der

I'm trying to decode the RSA private key which was DER encoded earlier without CRT components (p, q, dmp1, dmq1 and iqmp is NULL). I'm using same openssl version for both encoding and decoding, encoding works fine but decode fails. In decode we call EVP_PKCS82PKEY() function, this is failing with below error:

469393408:error:0D078079:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:field missing:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:425:Field=p, Type=RSAPrivateKey

The above error is because field p is NULL, but with same p is NULL encoding is success. Any idea why encode is Success but decode fails?

Comment: EVP_PKEY2PKCS8 does encoding (only) not decoding, did you mean EVP_PKCS82PKEY? Encoding (i2d) doesn't detect the error, but the output is in fact wrong because it violates the ASN.1 spec in PKCS1; decoding is correct to reject it. If you want a DER encoding without CRT you'll have to invent, and implement, your own (and to use it in PKCS8 or (especially) X.509/SPKI get your own OID for it).

Comment: Thanks for corrections Dave, yeah I mean EVP_PKCS82PKEY(). My point is openssl should throw error during encoding only right? is there any bug in openssl that it is not throwing any error during encoding?